# setting Delegates on destination viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

*This is puzzling me.*

### The context

[The original tutorial I'm following.](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/)

[image]

Where the segue is added to the Main View via a custom segue:

```
- (void) perform {
    
    MainViewController *source = (MainViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destination = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    
    for(UIView *view in source.main.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    
    source.currentViewController = destination;
    destination.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, source.main.frame.size.width, source.main.frame.size.height);
    [source.main addSubview:destination.view];
}
```

The ***TextField*** is connected as delegate in the child View Controller. All things being equal I get the app crashed without any message.

---

### The workaround

In the Main View Controller, in `-(void)prepareForSegue:` I've added `[segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];` in the meantime I've added a property in the child View Controller `id<UITextFieldDelegate> delegate` and modified the textfield delegate as `self.delegate`.

This works, but the trouble is that I've to set the delegated methods in Main View Controller which is not quite efficient as I have more View Controllers to add.

---

### The Objective

**How do I set each View Controller to be the delegate for itself without crashing?**

Comment: please provide minimum "working" example. Thanks

Comment: [There we go](http://ge.tt/26Waatz1/v/0?c) Nikita. I took the [original tutorial](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/) project and modified accordingly. The textfield is on the second tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, let's see crash report. Please, do the following:
 1. Add Exception Breakpoint
 2. Edit it as in the picture

[image]

Comment: No luck with this approach. [Here's the image](http://ge.tt/1ToSbtz1/v/0?c). You may also take a look at the [project](http://ge.tt/26Waatz1/v/0?c).

Comment: The problem was `@property(weak,nonatomic)UIViewController *currentViewController;`.
It breaks ARC somehow. Should be `strong`.
The exception was EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Use Zombie objects to handle such issues.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, it doesn't require any additional code such as __view controller containment__. Successfully tested on my project as well.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate cause of your error is that the view controller that your views belong to is being deallocated. The fact that your views are on screen while their view controller is deallocated highlights a fundamental flaw in the approach of taking views off one view controller and adding them to another. View controller containment is the correct way to solve an issue like this.

Changing the currentViewController property to strong will fix the memory management issue you're seeing, but it's just a bandaid. Your currentViewController will still be missing rotation methods, appearance and disappearance methods, layout methods, and so forth. View controller containment ensures these methods get called for the view controller whose views are on screen.

[Here is an altered version of your project](http://ge.tt/18RQstz1/v/0) that illustrates how to use view controller containment. I think that will be a better solution than manually removing and adding subviews of the view controllers themselves. See [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) for more info on custom view controller containers.

Comment: Kyle, I awarded you the bounty for the swift reply and also because you made me aware of __view controller containment__, which is on my list of further reading. However the correct answer has been awarded to @orkenstein. As he explained it was an ARC issue with a _weak_ reference to the destination controller.

Comment: @carlodurso I usually do make properties such as your currentViewController strong. In my example it's not necessary since the view controller's view is in the view hierarchy, and that keeps the view controller alive. Without view controller containment, the other approach is still quite flawed. The currentViewController's views are all on screen, but currentViewController will not be notified of view controller events such as appearance and disappearance methods (e.g. viewWillDisappear), layout methods (e.g. viewWillLayoutSubviews), rotation methods, etc... This can lead to many bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom class for the destinationViewController wich will implement UITextFieldDelegate

```
@interface DestinationViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

And from storyboard add the class to UIViewController that has TextField
[image]

And make the connections for elements and TextField delegate.

Implement delegate methods.

You will not need the implementation of `prepareForSegue:` anymore. You will have two different classes with different elements. Only if you need to pass something from `source` to `destination` then you use `prepareForSegue:`

Hope you'll understand

Comment: Thanks Merlea, I understand your explanation but I've got a different landscape. I have to use `prepareForSegue:` because I use 6 different View Controllers in the application. If I set the Destination Controller as the  `<UITextFieldDelegate>` the app will crash without any message. Thanks for answering.

Comment: If you link the outlets in Interface Builder there's no need to set the delegate in `prepareForSegue:`, and then you don't need to specify that the `destinationController` conforms to the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol.

Comment: Davide what's your suggestion? Take a look at the attached project.